# How to used two different XPATH values for same key

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath

EX: Xpath for same object in two different portals are

- `//*[@id="abc"]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label`
- `//*[@id="xyz"]/fieldset/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label`

I want to use both values in same key. At run time if selenium webdriver should find anyone and proceed. I tried below one, but its not working.

```
//*[@id="abc"]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label) | //*[@id="xyz"]/fieldset/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label

//*[@id="abc"]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label) or //*[@id="xyz"]/fieldset/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label
```

Please help how to use or pipeline function here.

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis in both expressions. Here `label)`. Is it a simple typo?

Answer (score 0):

A simple try catch block should help you:

```
 try{
     //first use this
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="abc"]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label"));


   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    //if caught in exception then use this
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="xyz"]/fieldset/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label"));


  }
```

or you can use following clean approach:

```
List<WebElement> itemList1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="abc"]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label"));

List<WebElement> itemList2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="xyz"]/fieldset/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label"));

if(listItem1.size() >0 ){

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="abc"]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label"));

  }
else if (listItem2.size() >0 ){

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="xyz"]/fieldset/div[1]/fieldset/div/div/div[1]/label"));
}
```